# Why is the "developmentMode" flag set on a library ignored?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, clasp

I have a randomly occurring issue (haven't yet really managed to figure out how to reproduce this, it happens erratically) with GAS libraries where development mode simply isn't working.

The static version of the library is always loaded regardless of the actual state of saved files in the library. The manifest files are in order, I have two scripts on two accounts (A and B) that use library C as a resource.

Script A manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "lib",
      "libraryId": "<id>",
      "version": "33",
      "developmentMode": true
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Script B manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "lib",
      "libraryId": "<id>",
      "version": "33",
      "developmentMode": false
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

The library is at a static version 33 with dozens of changes and saves following the static version. I would expect script A to load the latest changes, but it's as static as script B.

I can't figure out what's going on.

I'm using clasp for sync if that matters. If I ditch clasp and use the built-in editor to do everything, after saving a new version manually, doing a few edits and then loading script A, it seems to magically start to work in development mode.

Using clasp after that (even to create newer static versions from the command line) will work for a period of time, and then randomly stop. One random `clasp version` command at a random period of time later will freeze the library at the newly created static version, and subsequent `clasp push` will be done, the files synced, but the development mode will cease to be enforced (even though it's on).

This would imply that clasp isn't syncing properly, but that's not true - opening the script in the browser editor shows that all the files are properly synced, saved, and showing changes well past the static version and the "development mode" switch follows the manifest files accordingly.

---

Upon further analysis, I suspect that it might have something to do with Google's caching servers? In this scenario: same Spreadsheet, two users on two different Google accounts accessing the Library in development mode, one is actually seeing development, the other is static. Clearing local browser cache and app data doesn't help, so it must be on the delivery end.

Google is having delays updating the development version across all users and all projects that use the library, maybe?

**Summary**

*What makes the library START working in development mode again?*

Opening the Library in the browser editor and saving a new version manually. Sometimes it has to be done multiple times to work.

*What makes the library STOP working in development mode?*

From what I can tell, `clasp version`, **but not always**. Yesterday I saved 5-6 versions with "clasp version" from the command line and subsequent `clasp push` commands did show up in development mode. It was the random Nth `clasp version` that broke stuff.

Comment: Is your project re-published if you run `clasp deploy -V <version> -id <deployment-id>`?

Comment: As mentioned by @ZektorH, I would try redeploying. I haven't had your exact issue, but I've definitely noticed that published web apps fail after running `clasp push`, unless if I redeploy. (Redeploying the same version works.)

Comment: I'd love to reply promptly whether or not this would help, but it seems to be working properly now, lol. I have to wait for it to hang again, and I'm not about to start spamming versions to test this.

I don't have a need for deployments, so I haven't noticed what's the behavior when using that approach. Thank you both for the suggestion, I'll check back here if it works.

Comment: @ZektorH Sadly, no, redeploying the project doesn't solve my issue. Just spent the afternoon tinkering with deployments and still can't figure this out.

The static version has now been deployed with 

    `clasp deploy -V 42 -i "<id>" -d "production"`

Static script B loads V42 static. Rolling script A loads V42 static (should be V42 latest).

Bizarre.

Comment: @ZektorH Upon further analysis I must conclude that it has **something** to do with Google's caching servers. In this scenario: same Spreadsheet, two users on two different Google accounts accessing the Library in development mode, one is actually seeing development, the other is static. Clearing local browser cache and app data doesn't help, so it must be on the delivery end. Google is having delays updating the development version across all users and all projects that use the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the attempted steps to solve this, there is no clear solution.

## Attempted steps:

### Republish after `push` from clasp

Running `clasp deploy -V <version> -id <deployment-id>`

## Outcome:

If you are a subscriber to a G Suite account, please [contact the G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) for assistance.

Comment: I did notice the frequency of the random issue has reduced since I added a `clasp deploy` line to my deployment PowerShell script. :) It still occasionally hangs regardless of the deploy, but more often than not a subsequent deploy will nudge the script to freedom (while a mere `clasp push` would be completely useless). Thanks again!